# PyTorch - Generate New CNN Model from Pre-trained Model calling layer names

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I'd like to generate a new model from a pre-trained model by calling the layer names. I realize it's possible to access consecutive layers using a for loop, but I'm trying to load using the layer names. If it's not already obvious from the question, I'm new to python.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Net()
```

#I train this model so net contains my trained parameters

```
PATH = /mydrive/net

torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

#In the future, I want to generate a new model using a few of the layers from net model:

```
sub_layers = ['conv1.weight', 'conv1.bias','conv2.weight','conv2.bias']

checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)

new_model = Net()
new_model.load_state_dic(checkpoint['model_state_dict'],params=sub_layers, strict=False)
new_model.eval()
```

ERROR:

TypeError: load_state_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'

---

I realize that I could use a for loop similar to the one below. However in this case I'm trying to use the 'string' layer names.

```
for i in range(len(net.layers) -3):
    new_model.layers[i].set_weights(net.layers[i].get_weights())
```

I have read a number of different posts on how to save/load/warm start but the PyTorch helper code and stackoverflow related questions don't appear to address my specific question.